# Resizing colorbox after loading HTML content into a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, colorbox

I've ventured to any and all of the posts here about colorbox resizing issues, div properties and numerous other things!  Anyway, this very VERY simple piece of code is driving me up a wall and I wonder if it couldn't be answered?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text").load("<%= Model.FileLocation %>");
    $.fn.colorbox.resize();
});
</script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Above is the code (which, I would imagine - should work like a charm).  I've tried using a $.get and putting the resize in a callback, using timeouts and separating things with functions.

I've also verified that nothing is broken, the text is being loaded (doing an alert with $("#text") as the message shows me the loaded text.  Also I can specify widths and/or heights for the resize function and they work find, however, I can't do this based on the loaded content.

Sorry for the long-winded post... any ideas why in the world this thing will not resize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to anyone who read and tried to come up with a reason to why this didn't work, however, I finally found a work-around.

It appears that for some reason, even putting the `resize()` in a success callback, it was still getting called too early.  I was able to open firebug and manually enter the `colorbox.resize()` function in the command line and it worked just fine after loading, even though the callback failed.

So what I did was this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.async = false;

        $('#text').load('<%= Model.FileLocation %>');
        $.fn.colorbox.resize();
});
```

Setting the `async` in ajax to false forced it to be called in turn, and now it works great and is loading very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Try waiting until the content is actually loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text").load("<%= Model.FileLocation %>", function() {
         $.fn.colorbox.resize();
    });
});
</script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: (Deleted earlier comment) I did actually try that initially and it wasn't working.  After seeing the answer I decided to try again and it worked ONE time (and took a good 5+ seconds to finally kick off the resize function).  Now it doesn't do anything, cleared cache, restarted browser etc.  Resize still does nothing, even inside the callback >.>

Comment: I would have up-voted your post if I was allowed as its the reason that caused me to check to make sure the async call wasn't screwing it up (which it was).  Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem, just happy you figured it out.