# Jquery colorbox not resizing properly after $.html()

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have this code in success hook on ajax event:

```
success: function (data) {
    $(loadTarget).html(data.details);
    $.colorbox.resize();
}
```

`loadTarget` is div in already opened colorbox.

Problem is that color box will sometimes not resize properly, as if $.html() was asynchronous.

According to this question [Resizing colorbox after loading HTML content into a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934720/resizing-colorbox-after-loading-html-content-into-a-div) Ajax callback work somehow mysteriously and that they are responsible for this, but I don't understand how that could be a reason if $.html() is in ajax callback too.

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be issue of images.

`$.html()` just inserted img tags, and `$.colorbox.resize()` happened before images were loaded.

Found two ways to fix

1. Using jquery Load hook
2. Setting height property to img that (if known)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link
https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

```
    success (Local Event)
```

This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).

That means the success function is actually called if the ajax request made is successful only. It means the data might not be used or processed by other functions or operations yet!

That might be the reason for this behavior of yours.!

Comment: my problem is that resize will not properly accommodate changes in content made by ajax call. if ajax fails, there are no changes and no need for resize.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle in order to better understand the scenario ?